# getWindowHandle() throws error message "Nullpointerexception"

Tags: selenium

this is a simple selenium function that is trying to get a windowhandle.

right at that statement it throws" Nullpointerexception"

[image: Error]

```html
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WindowHandles {
 WebDriver achromeDriver;
 String abaseUrl; 

 
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  
  abaseUrl = "http://letskodeit.teachable.com/pages/practice";
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\ChromeDirver\\chromedriver.exe");
  
  achromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
  
  achromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
  achromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();;  
  
  System.out.println("setup completed");
 }
 
 @Test
 public void test() {
  
  try{
   
   String aparentwindowHandle = achromeDriver.getWindowHandle();
   
   System.out.println("the parent window handle is "+ aparentwindowHandle);
   
   WebElement aopenwindowelementbutton = achromeDriver.findElement(By.id("openwindow"));
  
   aopenwindowelementbutton.click();
   
   String achildwindowhandle = achromeDriver.getWindowHandle();
   
   System.out.println("the child window handle is: " + achildwindowhandle);
  }catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  }
  
    
  
 }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you declare `WebDriver achromeDriver;` as `static`?

Comment: same error. doesn't make any difference

Comment: did the browser launch, and did you see "setup completed" in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more details about your usecase and your observation would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However, it seems as you are using the `junit` framework and in-absence of any of the annotations the **`setUp()`** method is never executed.

As the `test()` method is annotated with `@Test` the program reaches there with `achromeDriver` as **`Null`**

---

### Solution

A quick solution would be to add `@Before` annotation to `setUp()` method as follows:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    abaseUrl = "http://letskodeit.teachable.com/pages/practice";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\ChromeDirver\\chromedriver.exe");
    achromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    achromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    achromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();;        
    System.out.println("setup completed");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much DebanjanB. It works after I added the annotation

Comment: sorry. my bad. it is not working. It can't find the button "openwindow" . But I am able to inspect that element and "openwindow" exits. I tried to find it with "id" and "xpath" also. The error says "Nosuchelement"                                                                              
   WebElement aopenwindowelementbutton = achromeDriver.findElement(By.id("openwindow"));

Comment: @bnath002 This answer caters to the issue of Nullpointerexception which you were facing. Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?